# rendering list from array in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, render

I'm loosing my mind because I don't understand why the list tags are not rendered in my web. Can someone see what's wrong in the code???

```
import "./resultBox.css"
import { useRef } from "react"

export default function ResultBox(props){
const resultBox = useRef()
const {resultados} = props

if (resultados != undefined){

    return(
        <div ref={resultBox} id="result-box">
            <ul>
                {resultados.users.map(user => {
                    <li key={user._id}>{user.first_name}</li>
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Thanks!!!

Comment: If you console log ``resultados`` what do you get?

Comment: Whenever you are using an `if` block, always put an `else` block to print a message; such as `resultados is undefined`.

Comment: Your `map` function doesn't return anything.

Comment: [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) have implicit return, unless you're using curly brackets, in which case you have to specify the `return`. This means `user => <li key={user._id}>{user.first_name}</li>` is the same as `user => (<li key={user._id}>{user.first_name}</li>)` and the same as `user => { return <li key={user._id}>{user.first_name}</li> }`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Like what @Dave Newton said, your `map` function doesn't return anything.
Take this example from where I did a similar thing the other day

```
 const items = historyItems.map((item, index) =>  <HistoryItem key={index} item={item} hourlyRate={props.hourlyRate}/>);
return (<div className="main-history">
    {items}
</div>);
```